# Strange issue since entityframework update

Tags: entity-framework, xamarin, mono

I am working on a Linux .Net application. This is a classical Xamarin .Net console application.

This application is working with a mysql database and entityframework.

This application was working fine.

This morning, i wanted to update dependency packages.
I updated the .Net framework version too.

Here are the version i am working with:

- .Net framework 4.6.2
- Entityframework 6.2.0
- Google.Protobuf 3.5.1 (this package has appeared)
- Mysql.Data 8.0.11
- Mysql.data.Entity 6.10.7

Now, when my program tries to work with the database, i have this string error:

> System.Data.Entity.Core.ProviderIncompatibleException: The provider
>   did not return a ProviderManifestToken string. --->
>   System.MethodAccessException: Method
>   `MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices:GetDbProviderManifestToken
>   (System.Data.Common.DbConnection)' is inaccessible from method`
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection:get_Settings ()'

I don't know what to do.

Here is the mono version on Linux server:

```
# mono --version
Mono JIT compiler version 4.6.2 (Stable 4.6.2.7/08fd525 Mon Nov 21 12:08:40 UTC 2016)
Copyright (C) 2002-2014 Novell, Inc, Xamarin Inc and Contributors. www.mono-project.com
    TLS:           __thread
    SIGSEGV:       altstack
    Notifications: epoll
    Architecture:  amd64
    Disabled:      none
    Misc:          softdebug 
    LLVM:          supported, not enabled.
    GC:            sgen
```

Comment: i do have a same issues, with windows environment as well